# How to convert datetime object to milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, milliseconds

I am parsing datetime values as follows:

```
df['actualDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['actualDateTime'])
```

How can I convert this datetime objects to milliseconds?

I didn't see mention of milliseconds in the [doc of to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Update (Based on feedback):
This is the current version of the code that provides error `TypeError: Cannot convert input to Timestamp`. The column `Date3` must contain milliseconds (as a numeric equivalent of a datetime object).

```
import pandas as pd
import time

s1 = {'Date' : ['2015-10-20T07:21:00.000','2015-10-19T07:18:00.000','2015-10-19T07:15:00.000']}

df = pd.DataFrame(s1)

df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

t = pd.Timestamp(df['Date2'])

df['Date3'] = time.mktime(t.timetuple())

print df
```

Comment: Paste some data `df['actualDateTime']`

Comment: Accept rai's answer if it is satisfactory!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: *"the doc of to_datetime, however there is no reference to milliseconds*" is simply incorrect, even [back in 0.17 doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) it said "**format**: *strftime to parse time, eg “%d/%m/%Y”, note that “%f” will parse all the way up to nanoseconds.*" And pandas strftime doc page refers you to Python datetime for more details.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try `pd.to_datetime(df['actualDateTime'], unit='ms')`

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

says this will denote in epoch, with variations 's','ms', 'ns' ...

### Update

If you want in epoch timestamp of the form 14567899..

```
import pandas as pd
import time
t = pd.Timestamp('2015-10-19 07:22:00')
time.mktime(t.timetuple())

>> 1445219520.0
```

### Latest update

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s1)
df1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
pd.DatetimeIndex(df1)
>>>DatetimeIndex(['2015-10-20 07:21:00', '2015-10-19 07:18:00',
           '2015-10-19 07:15:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
df1.astype(np.int64) 
>>>0    1445325660000000000
1    1445239080000000000
2    1445238900000000000
df1.astype(np.int64) // 10**9
>>>0    1445325660
1    1445239080
2    1445238900
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Comment: If I do so, I don't see any effect. The result is still 2015-10-19 10:39:00

Comment: is the desired o/p milliseconds since epoch, something like 146887891 ?

Comment: Yes. But if I replicate your code like this: df['actualDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['actualDateTime']) t = pd.Timestamp(df['actualDateTime'])
df['actualDateTime'] = time.mktime(t.timetuple()) It says: TypeError: Cannot convert input to Timestamp

Comment: See my update. I posted your code with my sample data so that you can see the error.

Comment: import numpy; and also no need for DatetimeIndex; statements 1, 2 and 5 are enough

Comment: The last 3rd update is plainly wrong: `df1.astype('u8')` converts into `nanoseconds`, and dividing it further by 1e9 makes it _seconds_, not milliseconds (that would be 1e6).  Anyhow, [@mike-müller's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33478399/548792) is succinct and correct.

Answer (score 19):

Timestamps in pandas are [always in nanoseconds](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html?highlight=timestamp#timestamp-limitations).

This gives you milliseconds since the epoch (1970-01-01):

```
df['actualDateTime'] = df['actualDateTime'].astype(np.int64) / int(1e6)
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]

Comment: @KlausosKlausos This is a Windows (or 32bit OS) problem. Updated to `int64`.

Comment: NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: `import numpy as np`

Answer (score 6):

This will return milliseconds from epoch

> timestamp_object.timestamp() * 1000

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.timestamp.html#pandas.Timestamp.timestamp

Answer (score 3):

`pandas.to_datetime` is to convert string or few other datatype to pandas `datetime[ns]`

In your instance initial `'actualDateTime'` is not having `milliseconds`.So, if you are parsing a column which has milliseconds you will get data.

for example,

```
df
Out[60]: 
                         a  b
0  2015-11-02 18:04:32.926  0
1  2015-11-02 18:04:32.928  1
2  2015-11-02 18:04:32.927  2

df.a
Out[61]: 
0    2015-11-02 18:04:32.926
1    2015-11-02 18:04:32.928
2    2015-11-02 18:04:32.927
Name: a, dtype: object

df.a = pd.to_datetime(df.a)

df.a
Out[63]: 
0   2015-11-02 18:04:32.926
1   2015-11-02 18:04:32.928
2   2015-11-02 18:04:32.927
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df.a.dt.nanosecond
Out[64]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
dtype: int64

df.a.dt.microsecond
Out[65]: 
0    926000
1    928000
2    927000
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yes I don't have milliseconds. However I thought it's possible to make such conversion. Well, to get seconds, should I use df.a.dt.second? I've tried it, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: you mean you want `milliseconds` not `microseconds` ?

Comment: Right, I need milliseconds. Also, I have 2015-11-02 18:04, not 015-11-02 18:04:32.926

Comment: If that solved your problem accept @WoodChopper 's answer.

Comment: It did not solve the problem. If I run df['actualDateTime'].dt.microsecond, I get 0 in all records.

Comment: So, what you are expecting to come?

Comment: I expect to get something similar to what got in the last lines of your example, i.e. 926000. So, the only thing I need is to get a single timestamp instead of a datetime. I will later use these timestaps for Clustering analysis, where I need all variables to be numeric.

Comment: so you mean conversion of (year,month,day,hr,min,sec) to milliseconds?

Comment: Exactly. This is what I mean. The solution of @rai seems to be correct, but it provides an error: TypeError: Cannot convert input to Timestamp

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, to convert a single Pandas timestamp object *to* milliseconds, I had to do:

```
import time
time.mktime(<timestamp_object>.timetuple())*1000
```

Answer (score 1):

For python >= 3.8, for e.g.

```
pd.DataFrame({'temp':[1,2,3]}, index = [pd.Timestamp.utcnow()]*3)
```

[image]

**convert to milliseconds**:

```
times = df.index.view(np.int64) // int(1e6)
print(times[0])
```

gives:

```
1666925409051
```

Note: to convert to seconds, similarly e.g.:

```
times = df.index.view(np.int64) // int(1e9)
print(times[0])
1666925409
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime

print datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]

>>>> OUTPUT >>>>
2015-11-02 18:04:32.926
```

Comment: It says: strftime() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not Series

Comment: I posted sample data.

Comment: I also tried thisdf['actualDateTime'] = (df['actualDateTime']-datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds() But it says that 'Series' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Comment: your values of datetime data are stored in df variable.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.