# Represent Pandas DataFrame Date Column in milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

NewB here.

I am reading a .csv file that contains Date,Open,High,Low,Close .... etc from Yahoo Finance, into a DataFrame.

Am trying to plot this data into a chart using HighCharts.  My initial reading and some samples about HighCharts seem to explain that to plot a StockChart, it needs date values in MilliSeconds.  And it definitely does make sense as HighChart is designed for such.

Now in my .csv i have the Date as 'YYYY-MM-DD' format, i am trying to convert this into milliseconds.

a simple code

```
from datetime import datetime
dt=datetime.strptime('2022-01-22','%Y-%m-%d')
print(dt)
millisec = dt*1000
print(millisec)
```

```
[OutPut]
2022-01-22 00:00:00
1642798800000.0
```

now if I try this with Pandas am not abt to figure out how to ....  I read the documentation but not sure my situation is address in there.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html

This is how my code looks like and the following Error:

```
import pandas as pd
# reading csv file into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('stock.csv')
# checking column data types
print(df.dtypes)
# creating new column to store TimeStamp  This is where i get the error
df['TimeStamped'] = pd.Timestamp(df['Date'],unit='ms')
```

```
[OutPut]
Date    object
Open    float64
High    float64
Low     float64
Close   float64

TypeError: Cannot convert input [0    2019-12-31
```

Assuming that the Date column is Object, I did a conversion

`df[Date] = pd.to_datetime(df[Date],yearfirst=True,format='%Y-%m-%d')`

Its still the same error.

Appreciate any help to Convert Date to milliseconds.

Thank You,

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477604/how-to-convert-datetime-object-to-milliseconds) answer your question?

Comment: use `pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).astype(int)/1e6` to get Unix time in milliseconds

Comment: @MrFuppes Thank you for the response,I get the following Error
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]

Comment: that seems to happen with older versions of pandas; you can use numpy type here instead; `pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).astype(np.int64)/1e6`

Comment: @Tobi208 same error           TypeError: Cannot convert input [0    2019-12-31

Comment: maybe you should add exemplary content of `df[Date]` after you load the df from the csv.

Comment: @MrFuppes  That's it ....  that Did it ....  Thank you !!

Comment: @MrFuppes If you can post it as answer (the numpy part) then i can mark it as the solution to the question.

Comment: I just noted that this is not a pandas version thing but related to Windows, see the comments under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33478399/10197418) of the question linked in the first comment. Sorry for the confusion ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You @MrFuppes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# reading csv file into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('stock.csv')

# replacing [Date] Column 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).astype(np.int64)/1e6
```

> ### astype()
>
> a bit more clarification for those who do not know ....
> Python astype() method enables us to set or convert the data type of an existing data column in a dataset or a data frame. By this, we can change or transform the type of the data values or single or multiple columns to altogether another form using astype() function

and finally 1e6, i had no idea about this till i looked for it

> ### 1e6
>
> Python takes the number to the left of the e and multiplies it by 10 raised to the power of the number after the e . So 1e6 is equivalent to 1×10⁶.

Once again thank you to @MrFuppes.